# ngrx effects explanation : @Effect

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm working on ngrx effects, I met this code :

```
@Effect()
  loadProjects$ = this.dataPersistence.fetch(ProjectsActionTypes.LoadProjects, {
    run: (action: LoadProjects, state: ProjectsState) => {
      return this.projectsService.all().pipe(map((res: Project[]) => new ProjectsLoaded(res)))
    },
    onError: (action: LoadProjects, error) => {
      console.error('Error', error);
    }
  });
```

Here this effect is listening to LoadProjects action, when it is triggered, it executes an http call function (this.projectsService.all()) and it is mapped to trigger another action which is ProjectsLoaded.

***NB: The example above works as expected***

> return this.projectsService.all().pipe(map((res: Project[]) => new
> ProjectsLoaded(res)))

**What I did not understand is how it triggers ProjectsLoaded action without even listening to the http call result which is an observable, without subscribe() ?**

As you know, for normal observable making this won't work

```
const obs = new Observable((sub) => {
  sub.next(10);
  sub.complete();
});

obs.pipe(map((v) => console.log(v))); // nothing happen because we did not subscribe to the observable 
obs.pipe(map((v) => v)).subscribe((v)=>console.log(v)); // it works
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the inner `Observable` you mentioned is chained with the main `Observable` of the `effect`, which is subscribed by `NgRx` internally to listen to the `action` once `dispatched`.

So you can imagine it like chaining two `Observables` to each other using `mergeMap` like the following (from your example)

```js
const obs1 = new Observable((sub) => {
    sub.next(10);
    sub.complete();
});

const obs2 = new Observable((sub) => {
    sub.next(20);
    sub.complete();
});

obs1.pipe(
    map((v1) => console.log(v1)), // it works
    mergeMap(() => obs2.pipe(map((v2) => v2)))
).subscribe((v2) => console.log(v2)); // it works
```